# wp-admin redirects back to wp-login after any login attempt

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I am not sure whether to post this to the wordpress stackexchange or here, but since this is more server-config, I'd assume here.

My issue is a configuration issue. Here's my setup:

Docker instance runs on internal docker IP address on port 80
Docker instance runs nginx which is the reverse proxy (public-facing port 80)
reverse proxy (public-facing) serves docker instance with wordpress on internal ip address to the internet

The issue is a rather unique one, since when viewing the index page or other pages (about or other pages), it works just fine. Only when logging into wordpress does this issue occur.

1. I go to https://example.com/wp-admin and login
2. It proceeds to redirect me to https://example.com/wp-login.php after logging in (correct or incorrect information, with no messages)
3. From there it loops again and again each time I try to login, with no
   indication that a login has been processed. No 'password is
   incorrect', just shows the login page.

This isn't a redirect loop in the sense that the browser stops it (infinite loop), it simply doesn't process the login properly. In other words, I am able to view the page and submit the login, but it simply doesn't process it.

I tried disabling all plugins, even creating a fresh install with no plugins - I have the same issues. It leads me to believe it is either a issue with my nginx config or it is wordpress itself - which I am not sure at this point.

I am using this setup so that I can add new websites to the server (this is a dedicated server) easily and if I need to, reboot individual sites if I ever need to without bringing down all the sites hosted using the reverse proxy.

mysql is able to be accessed just fine, as posts and pages load just fine without issues. Only when attempting to login this issue occurs.

My reverse proxy config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

location / {
    proxy_read_timeout    90;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect        off;

    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto http;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 80;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;

    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.4:80;
}

port_in_redirect off;
}
```

My wordpress nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    index index.php index.html default.php default.html index.htm deafult.htm;

    root /mrparker;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    server_tokens off;
    port_in_redirect off;
}
```

Comment: Your question implies you are using `https` but your configuration has `X-Forwarded-Proto http;` - could the login process be trying to establish a secure connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely you have the default setting for login and administration set.

// Secure login and admin
   define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
   define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

If you have allow insecure (non-HTTPS) logins, you should be able to login over HTTP.  However, you also need to allow insecure (non-HTTPS) administration to access the administration pages over HTTP.

It is preferable to setup HTTPS and access these functions securely.  You can use self-signed certificates, a certificate from Let's Encrypt, or a certificate from any number of certificate authorities.

Comment: It turned out to be a partial issue with a plugin (Cloudflare's plugin), and Cloudflare's SSL was causing issues without the 'Full (Strict)' setting. I fixed by using a SSL cert from Let's Encrypt and using the 'Full (Strict)' setting for the Flexible SSL.